# In SoapUI I am using XPath to transfer property values, but always it is showing null

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

Below is my XML data

```
<Response xmlns"https://aaaa....">   
<Companies>
    <e>
        <Address>8/F Building </Address> 
        <Address2>. </Address2>         
        <BankAcctNo></BankAcctNo>        
        <BankBranchNo> </BankBranchNo>         
        <BankName> </BankName>         
        <City> </City>         
        <DisplayName> qwerty </DisplayName>         
        <DisplayName2/>         
        <Email/>         
        <FaxNo/>                  
        <IBAN/>                  
        <Locations>                     
            <e>                        
                <Code>11</Code>                        
                <Name>a</Name>                     
            </e>                     
            <e>                        
                <Code>l </Code>                        
                <Name>Branch </Name>                     
            </e>                  
        </Locations>                  
        <Makes>                     
            <e>                        
                <Code>Test</Code>                        
                <Name> test</Name>                     
            </e>                  
        </Makes>                  
        <Name> Test </Name>                  
        <PhoneNo/>                  
        <PostCode>876</PostCode>                  
        <Roles>                     
        <e>                        
            <Name>SalesPerson</Name>                     
        </e>                  
        </Roles>                  
        <SwiftBIC/>                  
        <VatRegNo/>                  
        <Web/>               
    </e>            
</Companies>            
<LoginResult>               
    <AccessToken> abc  </AccessToken>               
    <SessionToken>  bbb </SessionToken>            
</LoginResult>            
<SessionID null="true"/>            
<UserDetails>               
    <EmployeeNo> a </EmployeeNo>               
    <FirstName>qwe </FirstName>               
    <IsServiceAdvisor>true</IsServiceAdvisor>               
    <LastName>One</LastName>               
    <SalesPersonCode>SP1</SalesPersonCode>               
    <SalesPersonDiscount>0 </SalesPersonDiscount>            
</UserDetails>         
</Response>
```

I want to pass the Makes->Code value to Xpath.

Comment: This is an XPath representation of a JSON Response. What is your XPath that you are using to perform the transfer?

Comment: You should read [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/266187). None of the previous commentators received your response.

Comment: @SiKing I tried with 1) //Makes/e/Code 2) //*:Makes/Code 3) /Makes/e//Code 4) //Companies/Makes/Code.

Comment: @SiKing Thanks i got solution . Its working fine now. I am using this Xpath /*[local-name()='Response' ]/*[local-name()='Companies'][1]/*[local-name()='e'][1]/*[local-name()='Makes'][1]/*[local-name()='e'][1]/*[local-name()='Code'][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just a simple `//*:Makes/*:e[1]/*:Code` would have done it.